# Calculating Current Year in 'yyyy-MM-dd' format sets the incorrect value in Java

Tags: java

Im using the following code to calculate the current year value in yyyy-MM-dd format 
however the below code assigns **paramStartDate value as 0001-01-01 which is incorrect
It should be '2014-01-01'**

```
else if(scopeSelected != null && scopeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Year To Date")){

                    Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendarStart.YEAR);
                    calendarStart.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
                    calendarStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
                    Date startDate=calendarStart.getTime();
                    DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    paramStartDate = dateFormat1.format(startDate);
                    setParamStartDate(paramStartDate);
                }
```

Comment: Also you can use Calendar.JANUARY for month (Java Dates are messy :-( day constants are 1-indexed, so I prefer defined constants rather than values).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendarStart.YEAR);
```

You're setting the value to `Calendar.YEAR` which is a constant with value 1.

If you don't want to change the year number, just remove this line completely.

(As an aside, I'd *strongly* recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time) instead of the built-in Java API. Joda Time is *much* cleaner.)

EDIT: For the new requirement of adding a year, you'd use

```
calendarStart.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
```

Comment: yes.  Always access static member variables from the class not an instance.  Helps avoid issues like this.

Comment: @Jon
Thanks , I need change the year every year so next year it will be 2015 , How can I do it ? 
Thanks

Comment: calendarStart.add(Calendar.YEAR,1)

Comment: @AmitSharad: see the JavaDoc for `getInstance()`: "Gets a calendar  using the default time zone and locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the default locale." So it will return the current year each time called, this is what you want, right?

Answer (score 2):

your expression `calendarStart.YEAR` refers to `Calendar.YEAR` which is a constant with the value 1. It is not the year!

Here one big problem of Calendar-API becomes obvious. It uses `int` as type for fields, not specialized object/field-type, so such errors become common. Compare it with new style in Java 8, namely:

```
LocalDate date = ...;
date = date.with(ChronoField.YEAR, 2014);
```

Note that in this other more modern library (built in Java 8) the object `ChronoField.YEAR` is not int, so such an error is impossible.

Comment: upps, Jon Skeet was quicker. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove this line:

```
calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR,calendarStart.YEAR);// actually your setting the Year by 1
```

Or Add the year like this:

```
calendarStart.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
```

And then try the code like this :

```
else if(scopeSelected != null && scopeSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("Year To Date")){

                Calendar calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendarStart.set(Calendar.MONTH,0);
                calendarStart.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
                Date startDate=calendarStart.getTime();
                DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                paramStartDate = dateFormat1.format(startDate);
                setParamStartDate(paramStartDate);
            }
```